# FlightOfferSearch sometimes giving back weird prices

Tags: amadeus

I have experienced a rather weird problem. FlightOfferSearch seems to return unrealistic prices, but only sometimes.

Example: ARN-DXB 12.11.2020 - 20.11.2020 return in Business Class finds a flight pair for 660 EUR. Now I checked the fare base that is used (PNCPSW), and it is listed for about 850 EUR for the city pair.

Checked pretty much everything else, travelerType, fareType and so on, but everything seems normal. This also only happens on some occasions.

Am I overlooking something or are you aware of any such issues?

Comment: Hi, I tried to reproduce the issue and I couldn't. Do you use the Flight Offers Price API to confirm the price you get in Search? Keep in mind that the test environment works with cache data and not live data. As it is not a technical question, our support email is better: developers@amadeus.com.

Comment: Good morning!  I haven't implemented the Flight Offers Price API yet, that is a good suggestion. I am in the production environment, where there should be live data, if I'm not mistaken?    How common is it for FlightOffers returned by the search to be "outdated"? I was expecting a technical glitch, since the price returned is lower than the fare allows it, but I will write an E-Mail. Thanks for the address.

Comment: UPDATE: I implemented the Flight Offers Price API, and the price is being confirmed.

Comment: Sometimes the airline have messed up the data. LH sometimes forget to put change fee data on a few of their offers, but there is cancellation fee data present. This corrupts the mini rules. Easy to work around when the cancellation fee is 0.. Maybe you are a victim of data corruption like I have been on occation.

Comment: Well, how do I put it... It turns out it was mixing classes without me noticing, because I had incorrectly set the parameters for it in the query. Thanks for your contribution though, I will keep out an eye for that.

Comment: You can maybe add it as an answer so it can help people who have the same question in the future.